# Angular: how to call input ngModelChange when value set for first time from httpResponse

Tags: html, angular

I am having few input elements whose default value is coming from HttpResponse and on their value change i am calling `ngModelChange` and performing other operations on it..but how would I get the value set on first time.
I tried adding `ngAfterContentChecked` but it will get called every time which will affect performance.
Is there any way to get an event to get first-time set value.
Current input box is

```
<input placeholder="email" (ngModelChange)="onEmailChange($event)" 
 [disabled]="disableEmail" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
#email="ngModel" name="email" [(ngModel)]="response.email" 
class="form-control input-xs"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You already have the initial value `response.email` in your component. Just call your `onEmailChange` action from the component.ts in your OnInit / Callback

Comment: Just a headsup, what you were looking for is probably `ngAfterViewInit`, which is called when the component has finished rendering. `ngAfterContentChecked` runs everytime after angular performed change detection.

Comment: as the response is coming from rest call, `ngOnInit` & `ngAfterViewInit` is already called till then. Only option I can think of is call all of change event functions(`onEmailChange`) manually.